# Split texts into smaller texts of n number of words

Tags: text, split

I have a large number of texts (several thousand) in a txt format and would like to split them into 500-word long chunks and to save these chunks into separate folders.

```
< *.txt  tr -c A-Za-z0-9 \\n | grep -v '^$' | split -l 500
```

can do the job but it splits texts to one word per line, whereas I would like to retain the original format. 
I was wondering if there is a bash command or Python script to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should also be able to do that with csplit, but I had better luck with the perl solution found here; https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/66513/how-can-i-split-a-large-text-file-into-chunks-of-500-words-or-so
Thanks to Joseph R.

```
$ cat generatewordchunks.pl 
perl -e '
         undef $/;
         $file=<>;
         while($file=~ /\G((\S+\s+){500})/gc)
         {
            $i++;
            open A,">","chunk-$i.txt";
            print A $1;
            close A;
         }
         $i++;
         if($file=~ /\G(.+)\Z/sg)
         {
          open A,">","chunk-$i.txt";
          print A $1;
         }
        '  $1
$ ./generatewordchunks.pl woord.list 
$ ls -ltr
total 13
-rwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf 5934 Jul 31 16:03 woord.list
-rwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf  362 Jul 31 16:08 generatewordchunks.pl
-rwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf 4203 Jul 31 16:11 chunk-1.txt
-rwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf 1731 Jul 31 16:11 chunk-2.txt
```